# android Cordova/PhoneGap HTML input box with Latin letters

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

When we try to put some text in HTML input box, no Latin letter is being inserted, no number or any of common signs. Only special characters like €¥£¢¡»«§¿©®ω⊙¤°℃℉ can be filled to the input. We tried switching languages and find out that for example Korean language signs can be used and they are shown more or less properly – some of them forced inserted text to be filled with previously typed Latin letters, that cannot be inserted directly. Another strange behavior is when we select whole text in input box then cut it and insert new text with Latin letters – only first letter is being shown, all other are not inserted.

We are not using default Cordova project startup, we are running Cordova inside Android native container application, starting it at some point. Problem does not occur on native input boxes – only on WebView.

We use following JS libraries: Cordova 2.3.0, jQuery 1.8.2, jQueryMobile 1.2.0.

Android versions: 4.1.1 and 4.2 (problem does not exist on Android 2.3)

We have 6 or 7 different devices and we can reproduce it on any of them - Android version matters.

Devices: Samsung Galaxy Nexus (4.2.2), Asus Nexus 7 (4.2.2).